# Which checksum algorithm is being used by adobe acrobat pdf for file attachment

Tags: java, pdf, adobe, pdfbox, checksum

I am using pdfBox for attaching some file into a pdf, file attachment is working correctly however I don't know what checksum to put.

When I manually attach a file and parse it through pdfBox, I see there is a checksum value like 
 [image]

I don't know which checksum algorithm is being inherently used, for sure it's not md5 or sha.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It IS MD5.

A quote from table 46, PDF 32000-1:2008:

> **CheckSum**, string, (Optional) A 16-byte string that is the checksum of the bytes of the uncompressed embedded file. The checksum shall be calculated by applying the standard MD5 message-digest algorithm (described in Internet RFC 1321, The MD5 Message-Digest Algorithm; see the Bibliography) to the bytes of the embedded file stream.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but md5 checksum looks like 8bd6509aba6eafe623392995b08c7047 , whereas the one which I get is having some special character as provided in question. am I missing anything?

Comment: Your quoted string is simply [hex encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).